# install JDBC on Amazon E2 server getting error "com.mysql.jdbc"

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-web-services

I have developed a java aplication that use JDBC. On to different ubuntu computers. Every thing works fine. But when i try to run the program on my Bitnami Amazon E2 server this part course me trouble.

```
try
   {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   }
   catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     System.err.println(e.getMessage());
     return;
   }
```

It throws the message "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

---

I tried to run the following command which works fine on a Ubuntu Desktop installation with openJDK.

```
export CLASexport CLASSPATH=:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

But it seams like the folders are not the same on the E2 server. How do I find the right path?

Answer (score 0):

Add the driver jar to your classpath.

Comment: I could not add code to this comment so had to post my seccond question as an answer.